# Mapbox style loading in the wrong place

Tags: leaflet, gis, mapbox

I'm trying to use a Mapbox style in my map. The style loads fine, but it seems to be way off. My GeoJson file should load points in California, and it works fine with other tilesets, but using the Mapbox dataset it loads somewhere north of Canada in the arctic circle. This seems like it's probably a problem with projections. The GeoJson file is in WGS84, which I believe is the Geojson default. The setview centers the view on the US using other tilesets but also centers the data north of Canada using Mapbox data. Here's the bit where I include the Mapbox data

```js
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'correct token';

var map = L.mapbox.map('map')
    .setView([43.64701, -79.39425], 4);

L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9').addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

Leaflet uses `LatLng` rather than mapbox's `LngLat`. Do you want your data to be around `[43.64701, -79.39425]`, or around `[-79.39425, 43.64701]`?

See also Tom MacWright's [explanation on why some libraries/formats use lat-lng and some use lng-lat](http://www.macwright.org/lonlat/).

Comment: Well, that explains why the data is off - thanks. How frustrating. Do you know how I would go about using leaflet together with Mapbox and get around this?

Comment: You just have to be super super super careful when dealing with coordinates, and inverting them when appropriate.